# Fragment is re-created after back from Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have a problem related to fragment life cycle.

Before doing this, I will set DONT KEEP ACTIVITY  mode(Setting -> Developer options).

In my project have 2 activity:

- Activity 1: keep and control Fragment A and Fragment B
- Activity 2: do not have fragment.

  1. Activity 1 will be called first, then Fragment A and Fragment B will be called to visible.
  2. Start Activity 2 from Activity 1, this cause Activity 1 will be destroyed and Fragment A & Fragment B will be destroyed too (Because of dont keep activity mode).
  3. Press back key from Activity 2 to back Activity 1

Problem occurs here: Fragment A and Fragment B will be automatically called `onCreateView()` after back from activity 2 -> I want to avoid this. Can you give me some tips to resolve it?

Update Code

- Activity 1

  ```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

      private Button mBtnShowFragmentA;

      private Button mBtnShowFragmentB;

      private Button mBtnGoAcitivity2;

      protected String mCurrentFragmentTag;


      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.layout_activity_1);
          mBtnShowFragmentA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_show_fragmentA);
          mBtnShowFragmentB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_show_fragmentB);
          mBtnGoAcitivity2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_go_activity2);
          mBtnShowFragmentA.setOnClickListener(this);
          mBtnShowFragmentB.setOnClickListener(this);
          mBtnGoAcitivity2.setOnClickListener(this);

      }

      @Override
      protected void onDestroy() {
          super.onDestroy();
      }

      protected void addFragment(int contentId, Fragment fragment, boolean isAddStack,
              String stackName) {
          FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
          String newFragment = fragment.getClass().getName();

          FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

          Fragment currentFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(mCurrentFragmentTag);

          if (currentFragment != null && !TextUtils.equals(currentFragment.getTag(), newFragment)) {
              ft.hide(currentFragment);
          }

          if (fm.findFragmentByTag(newFragment) != null) {
              fragment = (Fragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(newFragment);
          }

          if (!fragment.isAdded()) {
              ft.add(contentId, fragment, newFragment);
          } else {          
              ft.show(fragment);
          }

          if (isAddStack) {
              ft.addToBackStack(stackName);
          }
          try {
              ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();

          } catch (Exception e) {

          }
          mCurrentFragmentTag = newFragment;
      }

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          switch (v.getId()) {
              case R.id.btn_show_fragmentA:
                  FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();
                  addFragment(R.id.activity_main_content, fragmentA, false, null);
                  break;
              case R.id.btn_show_fragmentB:
                  FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();
                  addFragment(R.id.activity_main_content, fragmentB, false, null);
                  break;
              case R.id.btn_go_activity2:
                  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingActivity.class);
                  startActivity(intent);

                  break;
              default:
                  break;
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Fragment A

  ```
   public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment_a, container, false);

          return view;
      }   
  }
  ```
- Fragment B

  ```
    public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment_b, container, false);

          return view;
      }   
  }
  ```
- Activity 2

  ```
   public class SettingActivity extends Activity {

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.layout_activity_2);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onDestroy() {
          super.onDestroy();
      }

      @Override
      public void onBackPressed() {
          super.onBackPressed();
      }
  }
  ```

...................

Comment: Activity1 needs to rebuild the Fragments because they had been destroyed. How would you want to avoid that, and why?

Comment: Because fragment will be overlapped if activity has more fragment (ex 5 fragments). I want fragment call OnCreateView only when we call add fragment.

Comment: Then you should explicitly remove them when the Activity is destroyed on Activity change (in which case you had control over it), but NOT when it is destroyed on orientation change (when you had no control over it).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, maybe I should remove fragment in back press event - activity 2, but I control remove fragment base on fragment tag, if activity has added 5 fragment (for exsample), i cant make the code to remove all fragment that added before.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to remove activity from stack.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

                if (fragmentManager .getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                    fragmentManager .popBackStack();
                }
```

Comment: I have try your code on OnCreate - Activity 1 but it doesnt solve my problem. Because I do not add fragment into back stack.

Comment: I try but it doesnt work. I just updated my code. Can you help me check it again?